# How to inject indexable info to APM transaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, elk

I'm using **Programmatic API setup to self-attachedit** and I want to add indexable info to a transaction. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/public-api.html#api-tracer-api)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I updated my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation I found a way to do it. We can use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/1.x/public-api.html#api-transaction-add-tag `transaction.setLabel("authorities", authorities);` for that. Here is an example.

```
public class ApmContextDecorator extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final SecuredAdminUtils securedAdminUtils;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final Transaction transaction = ElasticApm.currentTransaction();

        setUserData(transaction);
        setCustomContext(transaction);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void setUserData(Transaction transaction) {
        final String userId = Try.of(() -> securedAdminUtils.getClaim("userId")).getOrNull();
        final String username = Try.of(() -> securedAdminUtils.getClaim("sub")).getOrNull();

        transaction.setUser(userId, "", username);
    }

    private void setCustomContext(Transaction transaction) {
        final List<String> roles = Try.of(securedAdminUtils::getRoles).getOrElse(List.of());
        final String authorities = String.join(",", roles);

        transaction.setLabel("organization", Try.of(() -> securedAdminUtils.getClaim("organization")).getOrNull());
        transaction.setLabel("authorities", authorities);
    }
}
```